# Why do I need to put a class name in <xxx> after .Query? with a database access user SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code I am reviewing:

```
           var phrases = db2
                .Query<Phrase>("SELECT C.Id As CategoryId" +
                              " FROM Category AS C" +
                              " JOIN Phrase AS P ON C.Id =          P.CategoryId");
```

The Phrase class seems not to be related to the C.Id.

Can someone explain, is it necessary to put some class between the < > here when doing a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using strings as a query it's impossible to know what kind of object comes out. That is why you specify it like that.

So by saying `var phrases = db2.Query<Phrase>("SELECT C.Id As CategoryId" +` you specify a `Phrase` object is coming out so the `phrases` variable will be typed as one.

Hope that makes any sense.